# How to start using Telerik controls in existing asp.net applicaton?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a web-forms application made in visual studio 2010.

I am new on telrik controls, i need information if we use trial version , how can i start using it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download telerik kit, from its website, it will give you trial version. You need to then install that kit, and then add its .dll file in the toolbox through choose items, and its control will then appear in the toolbox, you might have to close visual studio and again restart it , contorls to appear in toolbox. and then just drag and drop the control you want.

If you want full version, you will have to buy kit of telrik, then you will get licensed telrik controls.

Don't forget to check out their Documentation and Tutorials page.